# Retrieve 'Last Saved By' file property programmatically

Tags: c#, excel, file

I'm trying to access the 'Last Saved By' file property using C# as part of an MVC web app.  I'm able to get pretty much every other property on the file from last modified date, to the owner and I've even used Shell32 to get really obscure properties.

However, I cannot find a way to get the 'Last Saved By' property when I am retrieving the audit properties for each file that I need to report on. The files I need to get this data from are all Excel.

Comment: That field is part of the Excel file, not the file system properties. You probably need to use Excel to read the value.

Comment: Welcome to the [so]. What is your exact need? Do you want to know where in Excel object model the value is stored? Or you have problem programmatically accessing Excel from C#? Please click [edit] and narrow down your question to specific problem, it is currently too broad.

Comment: Thanks DavidG. I was beginning to think hat might be the case. I'm trying not to use COM as we'll need to add that to our new web server

Comment: Miroxlav, apologies I'll try and be a bit more specific. I need to access the file property when I'm checking folder locations for their contents to show an overview of all the files and their properties but I was trying to do it just using fileinfo and then the extended properties. And yes, I want to know where I can access the property.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739835(v=office.12).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'Last Saved By' property can be read using the WindowsAPICodePack.Shell libraries.  This property is application specific, so it is not present on some files (for example it is available on .xls but not .csv).  The 'Last Saved By' file property is named 'LastAuthor'.

I used nuget to get the package and the code below to access the property:

```
        string lastSavedBy = null;
        using (var so = ShellObject.FromParsingName(file))
        {
            var lastAuthorProperty =     so.Properties.GetProperty(SystemProperties.System.Document.LastAuthor);
            if (lastAuthorProperty != null)
            {
                var lastAuthor = lastAuthorProperty.ValueAsObject;
                if (lastAuthor != null)
                {
                    lastSavedBy = lastAuthor.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the property in

```
Workbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(7)
```

Maybe it will have index `6` when accessed from the C#. See [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.builtindocumentproperties.aspx).

**Quick verification:** in Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) of Excel VBA editor (Alt+F11) you can type
`? ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(7)` and hit Enter to display the property. This is the Excel part.

There is also part how to call Excel from the C#, but I am not going to cover this one, you can find literally hundreds of answers and examples on this topic.

Maybe even more effective can be just adding reference to [**Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel** Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.aspx) and working directly, without Excel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  If I couldn't have used a more generic solution, I would have used this answer.

Comment: @Wheels – if the answer you added was more helpful for you, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in Visual Basic

```
Dim sffile As Object = Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.ShellObject.FromParsingName(fileentry.FullName)
                    
Dim sf As Object = sffile.Properties.System.Document.LastAuthor.value
```

Comment: But the question was tagged with C#. Someone else may be looking for a Visual Basic solution, but that's not relevant to this particular question.